# Cómo acceder al valor del background de un button en el xml de android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-button

En mi aplicación tengo un botón, que cambia de manera aleatoria de imagen entre 7 opciones. Las 7 imágenes están en la carpeta drawable, y las cambio dinámicamente al hacer click con el siguiente código:

```
    int cartas[] = { R.drawable.carta_and, R.drawable.carta_bengala, R.drawable.carta_count,
 R.drawable.carta_like, R.drawable.carta_not, R.drawable.carta_or, R.drawable.carta_xor};
        
        public int getNumAleatorio() {
                return (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
            }
        
    public void cambiarCarta(View view) {
        Drawable background = getResources().getDrawable(cartas[getNumAleatorio()]);
        view.setBackground(background);
    }
```

Me gustaría poder mostrar un mensaje distinto dependiendo de la imagen que esté en el momento de pulsar. Había pensado algo como esto:

```
TextView texto = findViewById(R.id.texto);
Drawable carta_bengala = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.carta_bengala);
if (view.getBackground() == carta_bengala) {
     texto.setText("Has elegido la carta Bengala");
}
```

Pero la referencia de memoria de la imagen carta_bengala varía con cada click, y por lo tanto, no coinciden nunca.

Había pensado que una buena opción, si se puede, sería obtener el valor del background del botón que aparece en el archivo xml, es decir, a este:

```
android:background="@drawable/carta_bengala"
```

Porque imagino que, aunque cambie ese valor de manera dinámica con la función, siempre aparecerá el nombre de la imagen que se muestra. Si consigo extraer "@drawable/carta_bengala", luego con un simple if podría indicar que carta ha sido pulsada.

Si se os ocurre otra manera de solucionar mi problema, estoy abierto a escucharla.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: para tienes el recyclerview para una lista y saber cuando se toque en cada item.